# Unable to load dynamic libraries (pcre,spl,gettaxt,mhash,snmp,sockets,tokenizer)

Tags: mysql, php, freebsd, php5

I'm a bit new to freeBSD and trying to set up a webserver.

I've managed to get phpmyadmin installed and phpinfo(); works fine.
But when i typ in 'php -v' i get some warnings:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/pcre.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/pcre.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/spl.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/spl.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/gettext.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/gettext.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/mhash.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/mhash.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/snmp.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/snmp.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/sockets.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/sockets.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/tokenizer.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/tokenizer.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec  1 2011 14:19:00) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
```

Also when i try to install drupal I can not choose mysql as database but I'm not sure if that is related to the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either those extension files are missing, or else they cannot be read by the user executing PHP (wrong permissions or ownership), or your `extensions.ini` needs to be updated to match what modules you have installed.  Unfortunately, all failure modes produce the same error.

If they are simply missing, you need to reinstall them.  I recommend using the `php5-extensions` meta-port, but you can also install them one by one using:

```
portinstall -Rc php5-gettext [etc.]
```

I see that one of the ones listed is `pcre.so`.  I believe that PCRE is now included by default in PHP 5.3.x.  Is this installation an upgrade from an older version of PHP?  If so, I think that the `pcre.so` line in your `extensions.ini` can be commented out.

For example, one of my test systems currently contains:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Nov 13 2010 19:28:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

$ cat /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini
extension=filter.so
extension=session.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=xmlwriter.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=posix.so
extension=dom.so
extension=xmlreader.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=simplexml.so
extension=exif.so
extension=zlib.so
extension=tokenizer.so
extension=json.so
extension=gd.so
extension=iconv.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=readline.so
extension=xml.so
extension=bz2.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=hash.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=ctype.so
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=openssl.so
extension=pdf.so
```

... and the directory contains:

```
$ ls -lA /usr/local/lib/php/20090626/ 
total 4672
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    33066 Nov 13  2010 bz2.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    20401 Nov 13  2010 ctype.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   231335 Nov 13  2010 dom.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    66043 Nov 13  2010 exif.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    48992 Nov 13  2010 filter.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   370277 Nov 13  2010 gd.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    16993 Nov 13  2010 gettext.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   170710 Nov 13  2010 hash.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    46473 Nov 13  2010 iconv.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    39465 Nov 13  2010 json.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  1972043 Nov 13  2010 mbstring.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    55648 Nov 13  2010 mcrypt.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    68010 Nov 13  2010 mysql.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   165450 Nov 13  2010 mysqli.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   144290 Jan 30  2011 openssl.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   180661 Jun 16 20:40 pdf.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   116922 Nov 13  2010 pdo.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    38100 Nov 13  2010 pdo_mysql.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    33347 Nov 13  2010 pdo_sqlite.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    40794 Nov 13  2010 posix.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    27386 Nov 13  2010 readline.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    74152 Nov 13  2010 session.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    58057 Nov 13  2010 simplexml.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel   405571 Nov 13  2010 sqlite.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    19723 Nov 13  2010 tokenizer.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    63158 Nov 13  2010 xml.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    44015 Nov 13  2010 xmlreader.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    59210 Nov 13  2010 xmlwriter.so
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    45523 Nov 13  2010 zlib.so
```

Notice that all files are present and world-readable, and that `pcre.so` is not present.

Finally, note that I have a dim memory of the order in `extensions.ini` being significant, in that loading them in the wrong order can result in module load failures.  While your symptoms don't currently seem to indicate that that's a problem, you should be careful to not re-order the lines in `extensions.ini` unnecessarily.

If you post the contents of your `extensions.ini` file and a long listing (`ls -la`) of your extensions directory, I may be able to assist further.  I recommend sorting your extensions sorted out, and then if your MySQL issue remains, we can tackle that.

Comment: yes pcre should be included in php5 that's why i cant just instal pcre from the port folder

Comment: Aah i see now removed it from the extensions.ini file. now it is not loaded as extension but as part of php. thnx!

Comment: You're welcome!  And thanks for finding my answer useful - you are my first accepted answer. :-)

Comment: Your answer is very clear and complete. I can't vote your answer up because my reputation is only 3 at the moment :P otherwise I would have voted it up. I would like to see more answers like this!